# Python Urllib print certain bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

i am wanting to go online through my python script to get the weather and print it onto my console. I am currently using Urllib

```
import urllib.request
responce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.weatherzone.com.au/nsw/central-tablelands/orange')
html = responce.read(35000)
print(html)
```

As what i wanted to print is only 4 bytes, the other 29996 are unnecessarily downloaded. These 4 bytes are usually between 35000 and 35500 with `class="tempnow"`always preceding it.

Is there a way to only print these 4 bytes, or even an even better way of getting this number?

Thanks

Comment: Sound like you want to extract a value from an HTML structure. Then you have to parse it with a lib like beautifulsoup. Thinking in bytes is usualy less helpful for HTML.

Comment: how about `html.find('class="tempnow"')` and `html[start:end]`